# How to process large dataset with AWS Batch Transform

Tags: amazon-web-services, bigdata, pipeline, amazon-sagemaker

I have gigabytes of data for which I want to make predictions using [AWS SageMaker Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/whatis.html). I have two main issues:

- data comes as Excel files and [AWS Batch Transform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/batch-transform.html) needs it to be in JSON format to be able to process it. Reading Excel just to save it as JSON is redundant and it's a big IO slowdown
- Endpoint can only be invoked over HTTP which means a few MB payload limit - chunking into such small pieces slows things down as well

How can I tackle these issues?

[Pipe Mode](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/using-pipe-input-mode-for-amazon-sagemaker-algorithms/) could be a potential solution but from I read it is used for training only. Is it possible to use Pipe Mode for inference to speed things up?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to perform some preprocessing and ETL operations either using Glue/EMR and then use mini-batches to send data to Batch transform.

A blog regarding the same can be found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/preprocess-input-data-before-making-predictions-using-amazon-sagemaker-inference-pipelines-and-scikit-learn/)

Thanks,
Raghu